# Trying to fix a mess with DC Power supply

Tags: power-supply, connector, camera, ac-dc, terminal-block

I am not even close to know what I am doing with the electricity, but I have a power supply of my 8 cameras that is gone bad and I think I can manage to replace it myself, but there is a big BUT here. As you can see in the picture - someone did a very "GOOD" job managing the cables...

[image]

I wonder is there a way I can arrange this mess a bit ? Is it possible to use a connection block for example - 1 for all "-" cables and 1 for all the "+" cables. They are 8 cables each, so I think I should get two 8 slot blocks and do it this way - something like this:

[image]

Can someone explain how exactly I should connect them, but explain like you are explaining it to your 10 year old son - with like images, drawings or schemas?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the high voltage wire. Is that mains voltage input on twisted pair?

Comment: You are most of the way there.  Your two 8-slot blocks plan is fine.  Please update your post with the make / model / link to datasheet for the supply.  Also, there should be a sticker on the camera or something in the documentation with the power requirements, probably xx Vdc (volts) and xx A or mA (amps or milliamps).  With this information we can direct you on wire sizes.

Comment: Also, the earth conductor is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would crimp all the wires going to the same screw into a single spade terminal; all you need to do is make sure that the *conductor* cross sections are within the specified limits for the terminal you select.  You may strip one or more wires to double the length required by the terminal (plus a little bit) and fold them back in to bulk up the wire bundle to fit.  If this doesn't work - maybe the insulation on the wires is too bulky to fit in the terminal's insulator - then I would lap splice all 8 wires onto a leader wire of the same or greater cross-sectional area, cover it with heatshrink, and crimp *that* into a spade terminal.

I share @user1850479's concerns about the AC input wiring and conspicuous lack of a chassis ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could wire it like in that picture.  Notice how the black negative goes to the 1st terminal, then loops to the 3rd, 5th, 7th and so on.  The red positive wire goes to the 2nd terminal and then loops to the 4th, 6th, 8th and so on.
Make sure that whatever gauge wire you use is capable of carrying *all* the current for 8 cameras combined.

Then wire each camera to one black and one red terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help and guidance, but after all I read, I've decided to call a technician to do it the proper way...

I thought it is gonna be easy, but as always... it is not! :)